# Aws eks InvalidParameterException error service principals [ec2.amazonaws.com] were not found

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-eks

While adding nodegroup to eks cluster I am getting InvalidParameterException. The full error is given below.
`An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CreateNodegroup operation: Following required service principals [ec2.amazonaws.com] were not found in the trust relationships of nodeRole arn:aws:iam:::role/aws-service-role/eks-nodegroup.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup`

But while adding principal policies to the role I am getting `This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies`

The version of aws cli I am using is `aws-cli/1.18.211 Python/3.8.7 Darwin/17.2.0 botocore/1.19.51`

Comment: Can you show the actual policy and what are you trying to add to it?

Comment: {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
         "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
         "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account id>:user/*"
       },
       "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
     }
   ]
}

Comment: I'm having the same issue. `aws eks create-nodegroup --cluster-name EKS-cluster --nodegroup-name NG --subnets subnet-08f0fc71 subnet-53032a18 --node-role arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/aws-service-role/eks-nodegroup.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup`

Gives me `An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CreateNodegroup operation: Following required service principals [ec2.amazonaws.com] were not found in the trust relationships of nodeRole arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/aws-service-role/eks-nodegroup.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup`

Answer (score 0):

In the new dashboard aws has changed the api for permissions and trust policies into 2 separate calls. So for adding trust policies you have to edit the trust and relationship tab on the far right side of the dashboard. [image: reference image]